# Chrome extension $.ajaxSetup equivalent for chrome.extension.sendRequest

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does chrome's chrome.extension.sendRequest have the ability to hydrate the request or response with different values the way $.ajaxSetup can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't.

Anyway using `sendRequest` is deprecated and was replaced by `sendMessage`. 
Many people mixed up [Message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) between parts of your chrome extension and [xhr requests](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html).